# Управление GET параметром

Tags: php, get

Помогите написать условие и проверки *GET* параметров

В упрощённом виде это выглядит так:

есть массив `$ids (1, 2, 3)`

```
foreach($ids as $id) 
{
    if (если $attribute1 отсутствует, присваеваем ей "1")
      {
      echo "<a href='/index.php?attribute1=1'>ссылка</a>";
      }
    else if (если $attribute1 существует и не равно "1", добавляем "1")
      {
      echo "<a href='/index.php?attribute1=1,2'>ссылка</a>";
      }
    else if (если $attribute1 существует и одно из значений равно "1", удаляем "1")
      {
      echo "<a href='/index.php?attribute1=2'>ссылка</a>";
      }
    else
      {
      echo "<a href='/index.php'>ссылка</a>";
      }
    echo "<br />\n";
}
```

И чтобы скрипт принял в таком виде:

```
$attribute1 = "[1,2]";
```

Comment: Не понимаю, `$attribute1` - это строка что-ли?

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно для чего вам такое условие о_О. Но и не мое, наверное, дело.
Думаю вот это должно помочь:

```
// Просто проверка на отсутствие и разбиение на массив строк, можно поставить любые какие захотите.
if (empty($attribute1)) {
    $attribute1 = "";
}
$attrs = explode(',', $attribute1);

foreach ($ids as $id) {
    switch (true) {
        // Переменной нет
        case sizeof($attrs) == 0:
            echo "<a href='/index.php?attribute1=1'>ссылка</a>";
            break;

        // Нет значения "1"
        case !in_array(1, $attrs):
            echo "<a href='/index.php?attribute1=1,".implode(',', $attrs)."'>ссылка</a>";
            break;

        // Есть значение "1"
        case in_array(1, $attrs):
            $key = array_search(1, $attrs);
            if (!is_null($key) && !$key === false) {
                unset($attrs[$key]);
            }
            echo "<a href='/index.php?attribute1=1,".implode(',', $attrs)."'>ссылка</a>";
            break;

        // Теоретически это код, который никогда не выполнится
        default:
            echo "<a href='/index.php'>ссылка</a>";
            break;
    }   
}
```

Comment: in_array(1, $attrs) - тут по идее нужно использовать строки: in_array("1", $attrs), но PHP и так преобразует, если вместо "1" значения "0" не будет, там уже неопределенности начнутся